# How to submit part of inputs from a form to another domain?

Tags: php, forms

When user create a post, inside the post form, I want to provide a button. When user click the button, it will launch an iframe and submit some of the inputs of the post form. When nested form is not valid, how can I submit those inputs to the other website?

Answer (score 0):

Two methods,  Javascript, and PHP

**Javascript:**

You can use [jQuery Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)  to do this by javascript.

Basic steps:

1. Use an "onsubmit" handler for the form
2. In the function for handling the submit, build a data array with data you want to submit and send to the second form.
3. Either return true (to allow the programmed submit to continue) or build a secondary submit if required.

This one allows you to build the validation you refer to client-side (i.e. in the submit handler).

**PHP**

Receive the data in the php form, then use [CURL](https://www.google.com/search?q=use+cult+post+data) in the receiving PHP script to pass data as needed to the second form.